# Why is the Settings page not being displayed when I click on the Settings button in the navigation drawer of my Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation-drawer, mobile-application

Error 1:

> Invalid constant value.

Error 2:

> The values in a const list literal must be constants.
> Try removing the keyword 'const' from the list literal.

These errors appear in this code (on the line with `Navigator.pushNamed...`) :

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_app/global/common/toast.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("SALARY CALCULATOR"),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        drawer: const Drawer(
          backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 22, 116, 192),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              DrawerHeader(
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.wallet,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  size: 45,
                ),
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.settings),
                title: Text('S E T T I N G S'),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/settingspage');
                }, 
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 30),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/login");
                showToast(message: "Successfully signed out");
              },
              child: Container(
                height: 45,
                width: 100,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
                child: const Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "Sign out",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 18,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

At the moment for the application I managed to finish the authentication part with the help of firebase, with register and login, after you create your account it directs you to home_page.dart where there is an AppBar at the top with the name of the application, I also created a navigation drawer where if you press ,a window opens where I have the application logo + the settings page and the profile page, the problem is that when I click on SETTINGS it does not direct me to the respective page

[a picture with a part of the code and all the files and folders in the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrOfp.png)

[and this one is with code from main.dart but I don't know what to change to get rid of that error/problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7K9eA.png)

Comment: Please improve your question by selecting a proper title like the error message, and be more precise what error you try to resolve (mostly one error at a time). I guess if you start to search your error messages online, you will already find a lot of solutions, especially as the second error already explains really detailed what is going wrong. Learn more about how to make good questions at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

On line 20 you created a `Drawer` with its constant constructor, so the child has to be constant too. So the `Column` is also constructed with its constant constructor, and now its children have to be constants. Unfortunately, `ListTile` can't be constant because a callback is passed to its `onTap` parameter, and that callback is not a constant. So the solution is to remove `const` from the `Drawer` constructor in line 20.

```dart
drawer: Drawer(
```

You can keep the `DrawerHeader` constant though, so on line 24 put the `const` keyword before the constructor:

```dart
const DrawerHeader(
```

Answer (score 0):

in your code you made Drawer a const and its child is column and one of its children is a listtile. the listtile`s property ontap will work only if its parents does not have any const. so by removing const from drawer will solve your issue.